# Nodes Not Showing Up On Device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In the xcode simulator everything works fine, I have clouds that start at one point and then move and then reset to that same point when the get across the screen. But when I tried this app on my iphone 4 the clouds didnt appear, so i thought maybe its because its an iphone 4 and its old so then i tried it on my friends iphone 5c and the clouds still didnt show up, it says there is 7 nodes on the simulator and on the device so i cant figure out why they arent showing up. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer without seeing any code. But make sure your devices have the iOS requirements need for the functions your using, a few SpriteKit methods need iOS 7.1 and up in stead of 7.0 and some even need iOS 8.

Comment: Ill try updating the iphone 4 because both the devices i used only had ios 7.0